# Google App Inventor GUI RIA framework

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dojo, ria, google-apps

what RIA framework are they using and a comparison with Dojo will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's java-based, and it lets you make apps for android.  It doesn't really compare with dojo.

Some visual programming tools that are similar to App Inventor include Scratch (from MIT) and Lego Mindstorms.

Some android development tools and languages that are similar to App Inventor include 'simple' from google, which is a visual basic compiler for android, and ASE - the android scripting environment.

Dojo is a javascript application framework - some similar tools include the google closure library and YUI.

You could convert a dojo html/html5 app to an android app using phonegap or titanium appcelerator, but it's still not really the same as app inventor.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I think it's still unclear about which is better cloud computing solution, java/adobe air/HTML5+js framwork.